# How to resize video to full browser window size instead of full screen?

Tags: video.js

is there any option in videojs to maximize the video to fill the browsers window instead of going fullscreen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for the old school full window mode before actual fullscreen was really a thing? Or are you looking to do something like [BigVideo.js](http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/)? I guess the distinction is, do you want the video to always be that size, or do you want this to happen when someone clicks the fullscreen icon?

Comment: When someone ckicks is the idea. I've seen this behaviour in some of the codeschool videos, as in this for example http://backbone.codeschool.com/levels/1.

Comment: not related to vídeo.js but if you came here trying to reproduce web videos full window, try [Windowed](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/windowed/?src=search) for firefox or [Floating](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/floating-for-youtube/jjphmlaoffndcnecccgemfdaaoighkel?hl=en-US) for Chrome